# Set value using elementbyid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am trying to set a value with Javascript using `getElementById` but it is not working. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Sorry if this is basic question. Have not used JS in a long while.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function setSymbol(sym) {
                //alert("hi");
                document.getElementById("personName")=sym;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="setName('John Ford')">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            new awesome.widget({
                "name": "<span id = personName>",
                "locale": "en"
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you mean Swift?

Comment: you can't assign a value to an element ... are you trying to set its text content? in such case `document.getElementById("personName").textContent = sym;` is the way to go

Comment: Is there any issue with the fact that I'm trying to change text within a script or inside quotes("<span id = personName>")? The widget does not seem to be recognizing the new text even when I force a reload of page using document.location.reload(true)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `.innerHTML` or better yet `.textContent`:

```js
document.getElementById('personName').textContent = sym;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I ought to change about "name": "<span id = personName>" for example with the punctuation?  This name field is actually the input to a widget and I can't get the widget to recognize the input. If I put <span id=personname> elsewhere in regular html, it is displaying, but the widget is not recognizing it